# How does `lseek` help determine whether a file is empty?

Tags: c, unix, posix, gnu, lseek

I am looking at the [source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c#L695) of `cat` from the GNU coreutils, in particular the circle detection. They are comparing device and inode and that works fine, there is however an **extra case** where they allow the output to be an input, if the input is empty. Looking at the code, this must the `lseek (input_desc, 0, SEEK_CUR) < stat_buf.st_size)` part. I read the manpages and a [discussion](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18449) that I found from `git blame`, but I still **cannot quite understand why** this call to `lseek` is needed.

This is the gist of how `cat` detects, if it would infinitely exhaust the disk (note that some error checks have also been removed for brevity, the full source code is linked above):

```c
struct stat stat_buf;
fstat(STDOUT_FILENO, &stat_buf);
out_dev = stat_buf.st_dev;
out_ino = stat_buf.st_ino;
out_isreg = S_ISREG (stat_buf.st_mode) != 0;

// ...
// for <infile> in inputs {
    input_desc = open (infile, file_open_mode); // or STDIN_FILENO
    fstat(input_desc, &stat_buf);
    /* Don't copy a nonempty regular file to itself, as that would
       merely exhaust the output device.  It's better to catch this
       error earlier rather than later.  */
    if (out_isreg 
        && stat_buf.st_dev == out_dev && stat_buf.st_ino == out_ino
        && lseek (input_desc, 0, SEEK_CUR) < stat_buf.st_size)         // <--- This is the important line
    {
      // ...
    }
// } (end of for)
```

I have two possible explanations, but both seem kind of weird.

1. A file could be "empty" according to some standard (posix) although it still contains some information (that is counted with `st_size`) and `lseek` or `open` respects that by offsetting by some default. I wouldn't know why this would be the case, because empty means empty, right?
2. This comparison is really a "clever" composition of two conditions. This made sense to me first, because if `input_desc` would be `STDIN_FILENO` and there wouldn't be a file piped to `stdin`, `lseek` would fail with `ESPIPE` (according to the man page) and return `-1`. Then, this whole statement would be `lseek(...) == -1 || stat_buf.st_size > 0`. But this cannot be true, because this check only happens if device and inode are the same and that can only happen if a) stdin and stdout are pointing to same pty, but then `out_isreg` would be `false` or b) stdin and stdout point to the same file, but then `lseek` cannot return `-1`, right?

I have also put together a small program that prints out the return values and `errno` for the important parts, but there was nothing standing out to me:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct stat out_stat;
  struct stat in_stat;

  if (fstat(STDOUT_FILENO, &out_stat) < 0)
    exit(1);

  printf("this is written to stdout / into the file\n");

  int fd;
  if (argc > 1)
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  else
    fd = STDIN_FILENO;

  fstat(fd, &in_stat);
  int res = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
  fprintf(stderr,
          "errno after lseek = %d, EBADF = %d, EINVAL = %d, EOVERFLOW = %d, "
          "ESPIPE = %d\n",
          errno, EBADF, EINVAL, EOVERFLOW, ESPIPE);

  fprintf(stderr, "input:\n\tlseek(...) = %d\n\tst_size = %ld\n", res,
          in_stat.st_size);

  printf("outsize is %ld", out_stat.st_size);
}
```

```sh
$ touch empty
$ ./a.out < empty > empty
errno after lseek = 0, EBADF = 9, EINVAL = 22, EOVERFLOW = 75, ESPIPE = 29
input:
        lseek(...) = 0
        st_size = 0
$ echo x > empty
$ ./a.out < empty > empty
errno after lseek = 0, EBADF = 9, EINVAL = 22, EOVERFLOW = 75, ESPIPE = 29
input:
        lseek(...) = 0
        st_size = 0
```

So my ultimate question is untouched from my research: **How does `lseek` help determine if a file is empty in this example from the `cat` source code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my attempt at reverse-engineering this - I could not find any public discussion that explains why `lseek()` was put there (no other place in GNU coreutils does that).

The guiding question is: When is the condition `lseek (input_desc, 0, SEEK_CUR) < stat_buf.st_size` false?

Test case:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# (edited based on comments)

set -x

# arrange for cat to start off past the end of a non-empty file

echo abcdefghi > /tmp/so/catseek/input
# get the shell to open the input file for reading & writing as file descriptor 7
exec 7<>/tmp/so/catseek/input
# read the whole file via that descriptor (but leave it open)
dd <&7
# ask linux what the current file position of file descriptor 7 is
# should be everything dd read, namely 10 bytes, the size of the file
grep ^pos: /proc/self/fdinfo/7
# run cat, with pre and post content so that we know how to locate the interesting part
# "-" will cause cat to reuse its file descriptor 0 rather than creating a new file descriptor
# the redirections tell the shell to redirect file descriptors 1 and 0 to/from our open file descriptor 7
# which, as you'll remember, already has a file position of 10 bytes
strace -e lseek ./src/cat /tmp/so/catseek/pre - /tmp/so/catseek/post <&7 >&7
# now let's see what's in the file
cat /tmp/so/catseek/input
```

With:

```
$ cat /tmp/so/catseek/pre
pre
$ cat /tmp/so/catseek/post
post
```

`cat` with `lseek (input_desc, 0, SEEK_CUR) < stat_buf.st_size`:

```
+ test.sh:8:echo abcdefghi
+ test.sh:10:exec
+ test.sh:12:dd
abcdefghi
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
10 bytes copied, 2.0641e-05 s, 484 kB/s
+ test.sh:15:grep '^pos:' /proc/self/fdinfo/7
pos:    10
+ test.sh:20:strace -e lseek ./src/cat /tmp/so/catseek/pre - /tmp/so/catseek/post
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 14
+++ exited with 0 +++
+ test.sh:22:cat /tmp/so/catseek/input
abcdefghi
pre
post
```

`cat` with `0 < stat_buf.st_size`:

```
+ test.sh:8:echo abcdefghi
+ test.sh:10:exec
+ test.sh:12:dd
abcdefghi
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
10 bytes copied, 3.6415e-05 s, 275 kB/s
+ test.sh:15:grep '^pos:' /proc/self/fdinfo/7
pos:    10
+ test.sh:20:strace -e lseek ./src/cat /tmp/so/catseek/pre - /tmp/so/catseek/post
./src/cat: -: input file is output file
+++ exited with 1 +++
+ test.sh:22:cat /tmp/so/catseek/input
abcdefghi
pre
post
```

As you can see, when `cat` starts, the file position may already be after the end-of-file, and checking just the file size will make `cat` skip the file, but also trigger a failure, as the code inside the `if` statement is:

```
error (0, 0, _("%s: input file is output file"), infile);
ok = false;
goto contin;
```

Using `lseek()` allows `cat` to say "Oh, the file is the same, and is not empty, BUT our reads will still turn up empty, because that's how reading past EOF works, so we can allow this case".

Comment: I think you got it, congrats! Actually, the problem is how things are worded in the source code and in the related discussion. This is not about skipping empty files, but about skipping files where there is still something to read.

Comment: *I could not find any public discussion that explains why `lseek()` was put there (no other place in GNU coreutils does that)* Here you go:  https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=876

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can you be more specific? (maybe add an `#c1234` anchor to the proper comment) I don't see anything in that discussion related to what root just explained in their answer. This thread seems only about skipping empty files instead of failing with an error message, but skipping empty files does not necessitate lseek().

Comment: @root It'd be worth mentioning in your answer that the `lseek()` condition only address the case where the parameter is `-` (i.e. `fd = STDIN_FILENO`) because the file offset is not reset by `open()`. The lseek test keeps `echo foo > out; (read; cat pre - post) <> out >&0` from barking an error, but `echo foo > out; (read; cat pre out post) <> out >&0` rightly complains that the input and the output are the same file. Same for `echo foo > out; (read; cat pre /dev/stdin post) <> out >&0`

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have to agree with xhienne, there is nothing there that implies that this is needed, although I am maybe not reading something between the lines here

Comment: @NiklasMohrin In my snippets `>&0` is a shell syntax that basically calls `dup2(0, 1)`, i.e. redirects stdout to stdin (the `out` file which is opened in R/W mode with `<>`). Similarily, in the answer, `exec 7<>file` makes fd #7 access to the file in R/W mode for the rest of the shell session, and `<&7` in `dd <&7` is a `dup2(7, 0)`, i.e. redirects stdin to the file. What is important is to share the same opened file so that the offset (SEEK_CUR = `pos` line in `/proc/*/fdinfo/0`) is also shared. BTW, the smallest illustration I could find is `> out; cat pre - post <> out >&0`